# Pyspark to expand/repeat all the transaction row from start date to till date into multiple rows, for each day and customer

Tags: pyspark

[Input Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsFwm.png)

I have dataframe for each customer many transaction and related attributes. i am trying to calculate the net balance for each customer for each calendar day from the start date of the transaction to till current date.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
customerID  TrasnsactionID TransactionDate TransactionType TransactionAmount
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
c1          T1             01-10-2021      Deposit         500
C1          T2             01-15-2021      withdraw        100
C1          T3             01-30-2021      withdraw        300
C1          T4             02-20-2021      Deposit         200
c2          T1             01-01-2021      Deposit         500
C2          T2             01-15-2021      withdraw        100
C3          T1             01-30-2021      Deposit         300
C3          T2             02-20-2021      withdraw        200
```

The output dataframe to calculate the balance for each calendar day, customer from the start day of Transaction to till date. Deposit(+ve amount), withdraw(-ve amount)

```
CalendarDay  CustomerID    Netbalance
01-10-2021   C1            500
01-11-2021   C1            500
01-12-2021   C1            500
01-13-2021   C1            500
01-14-2021   C1            500
01-15-2021   C1            400(500-100)
..........same till 01-30-2021
01-30-2021   C1            100(400-300)
..........same till 02-20-2021
01-20-2021   C1            300(100+200)
..........same till current date
..........same till current date
```

So on for other customer from start date of the transaction.

My idea is to create intermediate dataframe for each calendar date and customer duplicate all the transaction rows and then apply filter and group by aggregate will give the output. Any help greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** create a dataframe containing all relevant calendar days for each `customerID` using [sequence](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#sequence) and [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#explode):

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from datetime import date

df = <input dataframe>

minDate = df.selectExpr("min(TransactionDate)").first()[0]
currentDate = date(2021, 2, 22) #or any other max date

all_days = spark.sql(f"select explode(sequence(to_date('{minDate}'),to_date('{currentDate}'))) as TransactionDate") \
    .crossJoin(df.select("customerID").distinct())
```

**Step 2:** create a dataframe containing the transaction - if any - for each day or `0.0` if there was no transaction. Additionally the column `TransactionType` is used to translate the `TransactionAmount` column into positive and negative numbers:

```python
trans = df.withColumn("act_transaction", F.when(F.col("TransactionType")=="Deposit", 
        F.col("TransactionAmount")).otherwise(-F.col("TransactionAmount"))) \
    .drop("TrasnsactionID", "TransactionAmount", "TransactionType") \
    .join(all_days, ["TransactionDate","customerID"], "outer") \
    .fillna(0.0)
```

**Step 3:** use a [window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html) to sum up all transactions for each customer until the respective date:

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("customerID").orderBy("TransactionDate").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

trans.withColumn("Netbalance", F.sum("act_transaction").over(w)) \
    .show()
```

Result:

```
+---------------+----------+---------------+----------+
|TransactionDate|customerID|act_transaction|Netbalance|
+---------------+----------+---------------+----------+
|     2021-01-01|        C1|              0|         0|
|     2021-01-02|        C1|              0|         0|
|     2021-01-03|        C1|              0|         0|
|     2021-01-04|        C1|              0|         0|
|     2021-01-05|        C1|              0|         0|
|     2021-01-06|        C1|              0|         0|
|     2021-01-07|        C1|              0|         0|
|     2021-01-08|        C1|              0|         0|
|     2021-01-09|        C1|              0|         0|
|     2021-01-10|        C1|            500|       500|
|     2021-01-11|        C1|              0|       500|
|     2021-01-12|        C1|              0|       500|
|     2021-01-13|        C1|              0|       500|
|     2021-01-14|        C1|              0|       500|
|     2021-01-15|        C1|           -100|       400|
|     2021-01-16|        C1|              0|       400|
|     2021-01-17|        C1|              0|       400|
|     2021-01-18|        C1|              0|       400|
|     2021-01-19|        C1|              0|       400|
|     2021-01-20|        C1|              0|       400|
+---------------+----------+---------------+----------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

**Edit:** to get individual minimal transaction dates for each `customerID`, you can use thus code for `all_days`:

```python
all_days = df.groupBy("customerID").agg(F.min("TransactionDate")) \
    .withColumn("TransactionDate", F.explode(F.sequence(F.col("min(TransactionDate)"), F.lit(currentDate)))) \
    .drop("min(TransactionDate)")
```

Comment: Thank you werner. This helps and it is working . i have request to modify the code mindate with respect to the customer differs for each customer. For eg the output for the customer c1 starts from "2021-01-10" to till date or max date(02-20-2021).

Comment: Method1 is not working. I would like to get the for each customer Min(TransactionDate). and explode the it with till date and then join.

Comment: I have added an alternative code snippet for `all_days`